# Changing point cluster symbol color by expression (color ramp with manual intervals)

Tags: qgis, symbology, qgis-3

I am working on cluster map (QGIS 3.0).
My map display both "not clustered" markers  with color attribute based on manual brackets ( [1-1.9); [2-4.9]; (5+ ) and clustered markers (**red** color).

[image]

[image]

What I want : I want to apply the same color attributes for my clustered markers using an expression.

What I tried (based on assistant) :

[image]

Comment: what did u "try" ? your screenshot shows that your expression is invalid.

Comment: @snaileater my expression is given by the assistant. How can I transform it ?

Comment: The "assistant" is only trying to validate your input ... it is not correcting it ... but i'm **not** sure u can combine cluster and another symbology (that would be something dynamic, depending on the map scale ?)... what is your 'custon ramp' ? Have u tried something simpler like _"if my number of homonymes is greater than 10 then turn the cluster to red"_ ?

Comment: ok I can try nested ifelse. Have you got an example ?

Comment: Unfortunately I think the answer is that you can't do what you're trying to do. The cluster renderer doesn't have the full range of variables that you would need to base an expression on the values of the points in the cluster.

Comment: Or you would need to write an expression that duplicates the aggregation being performed by the cluster renderer.